# Angular mat-expansion-panel, text is to long and won't fit

Tags: css, angular

Im trying to use the mat-expansion-panel from angular, i've got it working but somehow its not getting displayed correctly.
The text that display when the expansion-panel gets uncollapsed is not displaying correctly. Everything gets printed in one line and the text itself won't fit in the expansion panel.

[image: Problem[1]

my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-theme-selection',
  templateUrl: './theme-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./theme-selection.component.css']
})
export class ThemeSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
  public themeList:Array<any> = null;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.themeList = [
      {
        "themeName":"Thema A",
        "themeDescription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      },
      {
        "themeName":"Thema B",
        "themeDescription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      },
      {
        "themeName":"Thema C",
        "themeDescription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      },
      {
        "themeName":"Thema D",
        "themeDescription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      },
      {
        "themeName":"Thema E",
        "themeDescription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      }
    ];
  }
```

.html

```
<div class="themeSelection">
        <mat-radio-group class="radioButtons">
            <mat-radio-button class ="radBtn" *ngFor="let theme of themeList" [value]="theme.themeName">
                <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title>
                            {{theme.themeName}}
                        </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                            {{theme.themeDescription}}
                </mat-expansion-panel>
            </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
```

.css

```
.themeSelection {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 70vh;
     margin: auto;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
}
mat-expansion-panel {
    width: 40vw;
  }
```

Basically I want the Lorem ipsum to fit and do linebreaks if necessary (increasing in height then)

Comment: Use `white-space: normal` or `word-break: break-word` in `mat-expansion-panel` as your need

Comment: It's so hard to find a correct answer for such simple css things. Im sorry for asking and thanks you for helping me. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap `{{theme.themeDescription}}` in `p` tag.

.html

```
<div class="themeSelection">
        <mat-radio-group class="radioButtons">
            <mat-radio-button class ="radBtn" *ngFor="let theme of themeList" [value]="theme.themeName">
                <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title>
                            {{theme.themeName}}
                        </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <p class="myClass">
                            {{theme.themeDescription}}
                        </p>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
            </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
```

.css

```
.myClass {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@kuklyy answer didnt work for me. Try this:

You should wrap {{theme.themeDescription}} in p tag.

.html

```
<div class="themeSelection">
        <mat-radio-group class="radioButtons">
            <mat-radio-button class ="radBtn" *ngFor="let theme of themeList" [value]="theme.themeName">
                <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title>
                            {{theme.themeName}}
                        </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <p class="myClass">
                            {{theme.themeDescription}}
                        </p>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
            </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
```

And then in .css

```
.myClass {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```